# Replace word with its shorter version

Tags: python, string, performance, loops, optimization

I have a text and each word in this text can be replaced by word that I have in another list if it starts with the same letters and it's shorter that original. For example, my text is

> 'abdafb basrt casds dsasa a'

and list for replacement

> ['a', 'b']

. Thus, I will get

> 'a b casds dsasa a'

as a result.

```
slovar = list(map(str, input().split()))
text = list(map(str, input().split()))
for j in slovar:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].startswith(j):
            text[i] = text[i][:len(j)]

print(' '. join(text))
```

my code has time limit error. How to make it faster?

Comment: Please tag with a programming language.

Comment: You may want to look into prefix-trees (aka "tries") to search for matching prefixes more quickly

Comment: What do you mean with "my code has time limit error"? What is `slovar`? What is `text`?

Comment: you don't need a nested loop. Iterate the replacement words once building a dictionary with the shortest word for each starting letter, then iterate your text once replacing your word for the dictionary one if it's shorter. You then go from O(n2) to O(n) which is a big improvement

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki OP's example data doesn't show it, but it looks like the words in the replacement list could be longer than one character.

Comment: Even if they are longer than one character, if you have replacement words `a` and `ana`. and you have the text `ananas` nothing in the question prevents replacing the text `ananas` for the shorter one `a` instead of `ana`.  Or does the OP mean longest subsequence? Question says : "if it starts with the same letters and it's shorter that original", so `a` is a valid replacement of `ananas`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Can I ask about details? As I understood, I create a dictionary of a replacement list {'a':1, 'b':1} and after that I iterate through my text but I did not get how I can get shorter replacements

Comment: I don't know where you got this dict. Your dict should be something like `myDict = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}` in your example (the key is a single letter, for each letter of the alphbet, the value is the shortest replacement word starting with this letter). Then you do: `text[i]= myDict[text[i][0]]`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki it's not gonna work because if we have "{"a":"aa"} and our text is "abcd" it's gonna be replaced with "aa" but should not

Comment: Yes, you want the longest subsequence (which is not clear from your question). Use tries as suggested by Erwin then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a solution based on tries below.

Considering `h = max(map(len, initials))`,

- worst case insert time is O(`m*h`), where `m=len(initials)`,
- worst case search time is capped at O(`n*h`)  with `n=len(words)`

For a total max compute expense of O(`n*m*h`).

Since it is reasonable to assume `n >> m >> h`, we have O(`n`), linear with the number of words to replace.

```py
class TrieNode:
      
    def __init__(self, max_children=26):
        self.children: list[None | TrieNode] = [None]*max_children
        self.is_end_of_initial = False
  
class Trie:
      
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()
  
    def _char_to_int(self,ch):
        return ord(ch)-ord('a')
  
    def insert(self, word: str):
        node = self.root

        for letter in word:
            index = self._char_to_int(letter)

            if not node.children[index]:
                node.children[index] = TrieNode()

            node = node.children[index]

        node.is_end_of_initial = True
  
    def get_replacement(self, word: str):
        node = self.root
        replacement = ''

        for letter in word:

            index = self._char_to_int(letter)

            if not node.children[index]:
                if node.is_end_of_initial:
                    return replacement
                else:
                    return word


            replacement += letter
            node = node.children[index]

        return replacement

t = Trie()

words = ['hello', 'world', 'hi', 'well', 'job', 'hellsbells', 'janitor', 'john']
initials = ['hel', 'w', 'jo']

for initial in initials:
    t.insert(initial)

replaced_words = [t.get_replacement(word) for word in words]
print(replaced_words)
```

Output

```py
['hel', 'w', 'hi', 'w', 'jo', 'hel', 'janitor', 'jo']
```